SSIS package not copying files when run from SQL Server Agent
I have a simple SSIS package that copies files from one directory to another and then deletes the source file. It works fine when run from Visual Studio. Although when I add the package to the SSIS catalog and schedule it via a SQL Server Agent job the files do not get copied over. The job history is showing no authentication errors, so I have no idea what the issue is. Any advice would be appreciated



I guess it's possible you may not specifically be getting errors logged, but the file copy attempts are still failing.  Have you verified that the SQL Agent service account can access all of the necessary files and directories?  (That is - if you actually sign on to the SQL Server machine with the account that SQL Agent uses, can you manually perform all of the copy operations that you are expecting the SSIS package to do?)

Is the copying just files and folders on local drives, or network drives?  If you've got path with mapped network drive names in them, then it's probable that the SQL Agent service account won't be able to access those same mapped network drives.

The issue was that NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT had not been granted access to the directories.
